# dos2unix in a variable

Tags: bash, dos2unix

I need to execute the `dos2unix` command in a variable.
With files we just do `dos2unix myfile.txt`.
How can I do that with a variable?
For example:

```
variable="bla\r"
dos2unix $variable
```

Sugestions using other commands are also welcome.

PS.: I cannot perform a dos2unix on the file from where I'm reading the text.

Comment: BTW, `variable="bla\r"` is putting two characters, a backslash and an `r`, in the variable, not a single-character carriage return. If your shell is bash, one correct assignment for doing this would be `variable=bla$'\r'`.

Comment: ...you can use `'\r'` or `"\r"` for `tr`, `printf` or (GNU's non-POSIX-compliant) `echo -e` because it's doing backslash interpretation itself, rather than expecting to use the character as literal input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for any external command here; you can use parameter expansion to remove `CR`s using only functionality built into the shell itself, thus both faster to execute (with reasonably short strings) and guaranteed to work on any system that has bash (or a similarly extended shell, such as ksh93 or zsh), even without dos2unix installed:

```
$ PS1='> ' # for readability, to distinguish output starting with '$' literals
> variable_in=$'bla\r'
> variable_out=${variable_in//$'\r'/}
> printf '%q\n' "$variable_in"
$'bla\r'
> printf '%q\n' "$variable_out"
bla
```

Answer (score 3):

dos2unix can read from standard input, so you can write `echo "$variable" | dos2unix`. Try this:

```
$ variable=$'bla\r'

$ echo "$variable" | cat -A
bla^M$

$ echo "$variable" | dos2unix | cat -A
bla$
```

Comment: Arguably, if we're following the POSIX echo specification, the output of `echo "$variable"` is poorly defined by the standard -- any backslash-escape sequences inside that content will make the output undefined (whereas an echo with XSI extensions will expand them by default). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html if you're looking for a fun time, and consider `printf '%s\n' "$variable"` instead when passing content unmodified (other than addition of a trailing newline, or just `'%s'` should that be undesired) is important.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But hasn't the backslash-escape sequence already been converted to the corresponding control character, when we write `$'blah\r'`? echo shouldn't see any backslashes.

Comment: Sure -- I'm not talking about this specific test data; what we're building here should ideally be reusable with arbitrary content, which *could* potentially include content with backslash literals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use use `tr`:

```
echo "$variable"| tr -d '\r'
```

or

```
tr -d '\r' <<< "$variable"
```